# How to call methods with the Graphics2D class in the constructor?

Tags: java

Every tutorial I've scene for drawing a circle puts `Graphics2D` or `Graphics` in the constructor like this:

```
public void drawCircle (Graphics2D g){

}
```

But then there seems to be no way to call this method because you can't satisfy the parameters.
What goes here:

```
drawCircle( ? );
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sure you can call it: `drawCircle((Graphics2D) null)` is one of *many* ways to call it. But note that's not a constructor.

Comment: @AndyTurner Why the cast is needed?

Comment: It might not be. Maybe there's a `void drawCircle(Graphics)` method, and you need to disambiguate. I'm just saying there are *many* ways to call it.

Comment: @AndyTurner: ah, but is it a "good" way to call it? Likely it will lead to the dreaded NPE. Original poster, please understand that most Swing drawing is done *passively* -- code changes the state of fields of the class, and these fields are used in a JComponent-derived component's `paintComponent` method to do the actual drawing. Please check out the tutorials for the details.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter not for this `drawCircle` method it won't. My point is that without any further context as to what OP is trying to do, if all you want to do is call it, just call it with an arbitrary argument.

Comment: @AndyTurner: I'm guessing (something I should avoid doing!) that this is just skeleton code for a method that actually has some meat to it, code that uses that Graphics parameter for some purpose. Shame on me for guessing though.

Comment: Original poster, please check out: 1. [Swing Custom Painting Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), 2. [Swing Graphics2D Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/), 3. [Painting in AWT and Swing: Article with more details on Swing painting](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: Nit pick: the code you've posted and called a "constructor" is not in fact a valid constructor, but rather appears to be an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

> But then there seems to be no way to call this method

That is correct. You should NOT be calling the method directly. The method should only be invoked from a Swing painting method, which does have access to the currently valid Graphics object.

> Every tutorial I've scene for drawing a circle puts Graphics2D or Graphics in the constructor like this:

Yes, well you need to read the entire tutorial to understand the context of how the method should be used, not just a few lines from the tutorial.

The basic code would be something like:

```
public class CirclePanel extend JPanel
{
    @Override 
    protected void paintCompnent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        drawCircle( g );
    }

    private void drawCircle(Graphics g)
    { 
        // do painting with Graphics object
    }
}
```

Note how I changed the method signature to "private". This will enforce that the method should not be invoked from an external class.

> puts Graphics2D or Graphics in the constructor like this:

That is not a constructor. You are passing a "parameter" to a "method".